# Flutter how to navigate back to a particular page

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have an app with multiple pages where some pages are skip depending on the user selection...

for example, I have the following page

**details.dart**

**contact.dart**

**address.dart**

**code.dart**

**summary.dart**

I would like to go to another page from any of the above pages...However, I want first check to see if they are in the stack and then pop to it. Otherwise push that page onto the stack

How do I do this in Flutter

Comment: Perhaps the method Navigator.of(context).canPop(). Have a look at this medium page. It has some useful information on pushing and popping. https://link.medium.com/9OxEJw0ZPY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` or `Navigator.popUntil`.

They are very similar however like the name suggests `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` pushes a new route when the predicate matches, while `popUntil` re-uses an existing Route/Widget in the tree.

You can read more about them on this wonderful [Medium post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31) explaining all options in greater detail.

Comment: thanks but how do you tell if the route is not on the stack

Comment: you can use onUnknownRoute .

Answer (score 0):

You can use routes inside materialApp, after home

```
return MaterialApp(
    home:... ,
    routes:{
       "/routeName" : (context) => PageRoute()
    }
```

and then call route name from any pages 
Ex : app in Contact page need to move to PageRoute

```
//Contact Page
  ... 
 onTap:(){
   Navigator.pushReplacementName(context,'/routeName');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use multiple `Navigator.pop`