# How to pop page till desired page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I have multiple pages in flutter

let:

Page A opens Page B,

Page B opens Page C,

Page C opens Page D.

i have not popped any of pages

now on any user interaction i want to navigate to page A from page D. how can i do that??

My question is somewhat similar to this question : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334442/flutter-how-to-navigate-back-to-a-particular-page)

the only option i know is using multiple pop.

```
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: When navigating from `D` to `A`, do you want to pop out `B` and `C`?

Comment: hope this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51535621/using-navigator-popuntil-and-route-without-fixed-name/51535958#51535958

Comment: As I understand u well, u want to navigate screen and pop all existing pages, if so check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65932174/10170295

Comment: yes i want to pop B and C and D too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pushNamedAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html) or [pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html).

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      '/d-route', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```